# Session arrays for Shopping Cart in php

Tags: php

I have array data like with multiple sessions

```
$_SESSION['cart'][]['id'] = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['cart'][]['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
$_SESSION['cart'][]['size'] = $_POST['size'];
```

Now I want to get the data like `Array ( [id] => 4 [qty] => 1 [size] => 1)` in every time I fetch the data with any loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I think what you want is an array structure like this :

```
<?php
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
 'id' => $_POST['id'],
 'qty' => $_POST['qty'],
 'size' => $_POST['size']
);

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart) {
    print_r($cart);
}
```

Note : the `[]` directive is for **append** an element into your array

Comment: the result is now like this   Array ( [id] => 1 [qty] => 1 [size] => 1 ) Array ( [id] => 16 [qty] => 1 [size] => 1 )

Comment: i want single array each time  Array ( [id] => 1 [qty] => 1 [size] => 1 )

Comment: This is a single array each time, but `print_r` is called inside a `foreach` so you will see this multiple times

Answer (score 2):

You should assign a key for each product like below:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['id'] = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['size'] = $_POST['size'];
```

You can get data as below:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
    var_dump($product);
}
```